# how to type object with dynamic key

Tags: typescript

I am not expert in **Typescript**

I have data like this

```js
{
    bike: {
      revenue: "$340.00",
      items: 3,
      orders: 2,
      data: []
    },
    car: {
      revenue: "$340.00",
      items: 3,
      orders: 2,
      data: []
    },
    revenue: "$340.00",
    items: 3,
    orders: 2
}
```

`bike` and `car` are dynamic `keys`

I tried to type it like this

```js
  interface Item{
    [key: string]:Data
    revenue: string,
    items: number,
    orders: number,
  }


export interface Data {
    "id": number,
    "name": string,
    "gl_code": number,
    "items": number,
    "orders": number,
    "revenue": string,
    "minutes": number
}
```

But i get some error

**Property 'xxx' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'Data'.ts(2411)**

[image]

[image]

what is the problem and How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `[key: string]: Data` acts like a general baseline definition for all properties of the `Item` object, and other named properties (`revenue`, `items`, `orders`) are checked against it. In this case, neither `string`, nor `number` is assignable to `Data` (because `Data` has properties that strings and numbers don't have), so you get an error.

You must define the two sets of properties separately, so that one does not affect the other, and then merge them together. You can't do that with `interface` declaration, so you must use `type` instead:

```
type Item = {
  revenue: string,
  items: number,
  orders: number,
} & {
  [key: string]: Data
}
```